# How Can I XML Serialize My Entity Framework Generated Classes for Web API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api

Entity Framework has generated a set of POCO classes from my data model (using the `Entities.tt` template) that work fine as far as they go - but because they have circular references (the `Airplane` class has a property of  `public virtual List<License> Licenses`, and each `License` class has a reciprocal `Airplane` property) they won't serialize to XML for my Web API requests.

If I annotate the POCO classes with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes then everything works fine - but those changes are lost if the class is regenerated by the template - aka anytime a change is made to the edmx.

```
#region POCO classes generated by the EF T4 template
[DataContract] // manually added and LOST if template regenerates this class
public partial class Airplane
{
    [DataMethod] // also LOST if regenerated    
    public int AirplaneId { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Certification> Certifications{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Certification
{
    public int CertificationId { get; set; }
    public string CertificationAuthority { get; set; }
    public Airplane Airplane { get; set; }
}
#endregion
```

I've tried creating a "buddy" `public partial class Airplane` and annotating it, but you can't declare the same property twice - so I went the next logical step further and annotated the buddy `Airplane` with a `[MetadataType(typeof(Airplane_Metadata))]`, and then annotating the metadata class - which as I understand it is the whole reason for their existence.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Airplane_metadata))]
[DataContract] // <-- This actually works, but I can't add [DataMethod]s here
public partial class Airplane{}

public partial class Airplane_metadata
{
    [DataMethod] // NONE of the [Data...] tags are recognized by the serializer
    public int AirplaneId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

It doesn't work.  The serializer is not reading the `[DataMember]` or `[DataContract]` annotations from the MetadataType class.

I've been surfing the web and SO for hours now, and I've yet to find a solution for this. Olav and Stephen have commented that I should go with DTO's ... but what's the point of having a T4 template generate POCOs if I just have to re-write them?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT1::** major rework for clarity.

Comment: Have you considered returning DTO objects instead of the entities?

Comment: +1 agree with Olav; it's a bad idea to be exposing your entity classes directly over the wire like this. Define a set of DTO classes that contain the properties you want to send out from WebAPI and map from EF classes to DTO classes.

Comment: I perhaps was not clear; I mixed my terminologies pretty poorly - I'll edit to clarify.  EF has generated the POCO classes to represent the data entities in the entity data model... are you saying I need to completely duplicate the generated POCO classes with *another* layer of classes just to serialize those classes?

Comment: I'm using DTO objects in my current project. I've found it to be a good approach to use in my situation where I have to work with a lot of hierarchical data. This MSDN article might be helpful to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx

Comment: Thanks Frank - I'll give it a read - although after more research (and despite my initial resistance to the idea) it looks like DTOs are going to be an excellent solution to the problem.  Mea culpa to @OlavNybø et. al.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know you said the metadata thing did not work for you, but this worked for me...

Put everything in a separate file (ex. Airplane_partial.cs). Like you said, you lose all changes to EF's files if you have to update the entities.

In Airplane_partial.cs...

```
public class AirplaneMetaData
{
    [DataMember()]
    public virtual DataType propertyName;
}

[MetadataType(typeof(AirplaneMetaData))]
public partial class Airplane
{
    // blank partial class
}
```

You could also read this dense Microsoft article and see if it can help you...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee789839%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: That is exactly the "metadata thing" that I tried, that did not work, but I will dig thru that reference and see if it helps.

Comment: OK well I am sorry it did not work for you. I am using it right now and it is working with the same kind of entities you are describing, but I am serializing to JSON instead of XML. Seems like it should still work though. Microsoft's solution is different.